# Convert 12 hour time string into datetime or time

Tags: python, datetime, time

Ive been trying to use `time.strptime(string1,'%H:%M')`, with no success

How can I get the following:

```
Input     Output
3:14AM  -> 03:14
9:33PM  -> 21:33
12:21AM -> 00:21
12:15PM -> 12:15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%I` for 12 hour times and `%p` for the `am` or `pm` as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
 
for t in ["3:14AM", "9:33PM", "12:21AM", "12:15PM"]:
    print(datetime.strptime(t, '%I:%M%p').strftime("%H:%M"))
```

Giving you the following output:

```
03:14
21:33
00:21
12:15
```

The formats used are documented in [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

The problem requires that you first `strptime` using `%I` for the 12 hour time and adding the directive `%p` for AM or PM to get a time object; altogther `'%I:%M%p'`. Then use `strftime` to format the time object into a string:

---

*Trials:*

```
>>> tm = time.strptime('12:33AM', '%I:%M%p')
>>> time.strftime('%H:%M', tm)
'00:33'
>>> tm = time.strptime('9:33PM', '%H:%M%p')
>>> time.strftime('%H:%M', tm)
'09:33'
```

Doc reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Answer (score -1):

You're missing `%p` (Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM).

```
time.strptime(string1,'%H:%M%p')
```